# IIS Integrated mode causing errors on Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, iis, mode, integrated

I have upgraded a site to IIS integrated mode and now none of my plain vanilla 301 Redirect pages (using Response.Redirect) are working...

The error given is:

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: offset

Stack trace shows this is being called from the .Flush() method on one of my pre-existing handlers.  The handler works totally fine on other pages just not when a Response.Redirect is called from inline code.

Is there a simple way I can recover this situation? I have some sites where there are 80+ redirect pages (CMS controlled)

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it's using "Response.AddHeader" - I'm presuming the module is running on every request and modifying the length of the response stream?